# Difficulties with nginx redirect to tomcat spring boot web application

Tags: nginx, spring-boot, proxy, tomcat8, webjars

I developed a small website with spring boot and thymeleaf. It uses bootstrap and jquery via webjars. Running locally, everything is fine and the js and css files are delivered correctly.

When I try to deploy it to my server, things get ugly. I have a default tomcat8 running, that's proxied to though a nginx.

The site content of the html file is delivered correctly, however, it can't find the webjars.

My application.properties look like

```
/example
```

the webapp is deployed to the tomcat as /example.

The script path in the index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
```

Even though I don't like to use CDN because I know to few about them, but anyway.

The error message in the chrome devtools are:

```
404 GET https://example.de/example/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
404 GET https://example.de/example/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js 
404 GET https://example.de/example/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

The nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name example.de www.example.de;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name     example.de www.example.de;
        root            /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/example;
        ...

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/;
        }
}
```

I also tried something like

```
rewrite ^/collectd(/.*)$ $1 break;
```

but it neither helped.

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.example</groupId>
<artifactId>example-website</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>example-website</name>
<description>example website</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.32</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anyone tell me what I have to add to the nginx configuration that it actually redirects to the webapp folder?

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be fixed be adding a missing rewrite directive to the nginx site (location) configuration.

The missing line was:

```
rewrite ^/example(.*)$ $1 last;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add Resource Handler in your configuration  as following :

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations(
                "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**")) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(
                RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, spring boot brings his own ResourceHandler and this step isn't necessary